# How does "Increased damage" work for Critical Strikes in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The new Essence system in WoW has me questioning how the behind-the-scenes match works for some on use abilities.

This [essence](https://i.gyazo.com/c307d188dd52b36ce4ec8744e38dc5af.png) states that "When it critically strikes, the damage is increased by 300%".

Using a damage recount addon, I have this [data](https://i.gyazo.com/8905d8e29f98de7a37530d7ec3cca896.png).

So if it regularly hits for 1308 damage, how would I calculate the expected damage with a crit and then 300% damage increase?

What I had initially been doing: A 1308 crit turns into 2600 damage. 2600 increased by 300%, which to me would land around 10,400 (since its an *increase* of 300%).

But looking at the data the damage is only 6750, which is much closer to 2600 * 3, but still about 1000 damage short.

Any info on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any other critical hit damage modifiers? Such as a racial?

Comment: ...and did you have by any chance any trinket procs or other damage modifiers?

Comment: I am a Tauren Shaman, so I have 250% crit damage. But that would just make the crit do more damage, not less. By all my calculations they are over the amount happening in game.

Comment: 2600 + 3*1308 = about 6750.

Comment: @Sjoerd that's not possible for a Shaman. There is at least one .5 modifier in the calculation (250% CD from Elemental fury)

Comment: Are you sure the wording is meant that way? I'd assume, it means a crit increases the dmg by 300%, either in addition to the usual 200% or instead of it. Meaning the final dmg would be either 300% or 500% of normal dmg, not 800% as you assume. 500% normal dmg would be 6540, so pretty close to your figure.

Comment: @dly It's not an answer. It's just an observation about the numbers involved.

Comment: @Sjoerd I just said that your statement was not true/possible, that's all. Just as a precaution.